# How do I turn off codetidy in TinyMCE editor in Umbraco?

Tags: tinymce, umbraco

I am running Umbraco 4.5.2. In config/umbracosettings I have made the change

```
<TidyEditorContent>False</TidyEditorContent>
```

In TinyMCEConfig I have deleted the valid elements and replaced with

```
 <validElements><![CDATA[*[*]]]></validElements>
```

I have gone into web.config, added a space and resaved - to get Umbraco to reload the config files.

In Umbraco when I add content, it is still being 'tidied' and stripping out tags that I want left in. I just want to turn the code tidy off completely.

Comment: Does the tags you want disappear when you toggle between WYSIWYG and HTML mode in TinyMCE?

Comment: yes - I just want it to leave code alone, right or wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to explicatively define the valid elements in the validElements section in the TinyMCE config. The behavior you are experiencing is not related to Tidy.

Comment: I thought that using a wildcard in the valid elements tag would have allowed this?

Comment: Yes, you would imagine so, but I have had success with the more verbose approach. Let me know how it turns out for you?

Comment: I just tried adding the line <config key="cleanup">false</config> to the custom config area at the bottom of the tinyMceConfig.config file. Didn't seem to do anything!

Comment: I have found if I edit in html view the code stays the way I want it. If I save in WYSIWYG editor it 'tidies'